# SharePoint Designer for SharePoint 2010 Compatibility Sites on SP 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I know that SharePoint Designer is supposed to be used with its respective version of SharePoint, but what about when you have a site collection on SharePoint 2013 that is still running in SP 2010 compatibility mode?

We need to make some edits before upgrading our site collection to SP 2013.  Is it best to use SharePoint Designer 2010 or SharePoint Designer 2013 in this case?

I can actually access my SP 2010 compatibility-mode sites with both versions of SPD, but I wanted to follow best practices.

Thanks,

William

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It is best to use SPD 2013** because even though the site is in 2010 mode it is still running off of SP 2013

Comment: Thanks - I had heard conflicting things about this scenario.